# Call a function when a new line is added to a log file

Tags: powershell

I want to tail a file and call a function when a new line is added. This is what I'm trying but it's not printing anything out which makes me think that the `Get-Content` isn't working.

```
function Check-LogLine {
    param (
        $Line
    )

    ...
}

$Global:Line = Get-Content -Path $LogPath -Tail 1 -Wait
Write-Output "Line: $Global:Line"
while ($Line -NotLike "*Stopping!") {
    $Global:Line = Get-Content -Path $LogPath -Tail 1 -Wait
    Write-Output $Global:Line
    Check-LogLine -Line $Global:Line
}
```

-= Edit =-
It gets the last line if I remove the `-Wait` but it keeps getting the same last line over and over.

Comment: You would need to use the pipeline, your code is never reaching the `while` loop because `-Wait` blocks the thread. Stopping the pipeline on a `-Wait` will be quite cumbersome assuming you also want to use `Write-Output` inside the loop. If you just want to write to the console (Host) then it's pretty easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're never getting into the `while` loop, `-Wait` is blocking the thread on the first call:

```
$Global:Line = Get-Content -Path $LogPath -Tail 1 -Wait
```

You can use the pipeline instead which is meant for this, I will go and assume since you're using `-Wait` this will be a somewhat interactive process and you only want output to the console doesn't matter if the output goes to the [Success Stream or the Information Stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_output_streams?view=powershell-7.3). If that's the case, you can use `Select-Object -First 1` to properly break the pipeline. Otherwise, if you really need the output to go the Success Stream, the solution would be very cumbersome.

Here is an example of how you can approach your code:

```
function Check-LogLine {
    param($Line)

    # Writing to the Information Stream
    # (this output is not passed thru the pipeline)
    Write-Host "[$([datetime]::Now.ToString('u'))] $line"
}


$tmp = New-TemporaryFile
# This job will run in the background writing to a temp file each 2 seconds
$job = Start-Job {
    $tmp = $using:tmp
    0..10 | ForEach-Object {
        Start-Sleep 2

        if($_ -ne 5) {
            "$_ ... Running!" | Add-Content $tmp.FullName
            return
        }

        "$_ ... Stopping!" | Add-Content $tmp.FullName
    }
}

try {
    Get-Content $tmp.FullName -Wait -Tail 1 | ForEach-Object {
        # The output to this function goes to the Info Stream
        Check-LogLine $_

        if($_ -like '*Stopping*') {
            Write-Host 'Stopping here...'
            $job | Stop-Job | Remove-Job

            'this output goes to Success Stream to stop this pipeline...'
        }
    } | Select-Object -First 1
}
finally {
    $tmp | Remove-Item
}
```

Comment: This seems to me working but anytime I try to `Write-Output` the script stops running. I'm guessing this is what you meant when you said the "Success Stream" so I started using `Write-Information` but it's not coming out to the console. Is there a way to view this information?

Comment: `Write-Output` goes to the success stream yes. `Write-Host` should work, if you're not seeing output to the console then idk what to tell you, really weird

Comment: `Write-Host` worked! I was using `Write-Information`. Thank you!!